# Python How to use a class in another class method

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes one called Aluno(Student) other call Curso(Course) what i want to do is using the student class to add in this course class if the requirement is met, but for some reason it is not adding the student to the current course Set when i use the definition

Aluno Class

```
class Aluno:
  def __init__(self, idAluno, nome, idade, curso):
    self.idAluno = idAluno
    self.nome = nome
    self.idade = idade
    self.curso = curso
    self.situacao_academica = situacao_academica
```

Curso class

```
import Aluno

class Curso:
  def __init__(self, nome, professor):
    self.nome = nome
    self.professor = professor
    self.materias = {}
    self.alunos = {}

  def ProcurarPorAlunos(self, Aluno):
    if Aluno.Curso.nome == self.Curso.nome:
      self.alunos.append(Aluno)
```

Comment: you made `self.alunos` a dictionary and not a list. try `self.alunos = []` instead

Comment: `{}` is an empty dictionary, not a set. To initialise an empty set use `set()`. And you would use `add()` to add items to a set, not `append()`. Probably the same situation for `self.materias`.

Comment: `Aluno.Curso.nome` - an instance of `Aluno` does not have a `Curso` attribute - case matters `Curso != curso`. `self.Curso.nome` - A  `Curso` instance does not have a `Curso` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but here is something that has some chance of helping you.

```py
class Aluno:
    def __init__(self, idAluno, nome, idade, curso):
        self.idAluno = idAluno
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.curso = curso    # is this a Curso instance?
#        self.situacao_academica = situacao_academica

class Curso:
    def __init__(self, nome, professor):
        self.nome = nome
        self.professor = professor
        self.materias = []
        self.alunos = []    # empty list, could also use a set, maybe

    def procurar_por_alunos(self, aluno):
        if aluno.curso.nome == self.nome:
            self.alunos.append(aluno)
```

`procurar_por_alunos()` adds a student to the list of students in a course. You would use it like this:

```
>>> physics = Curso('Physics', 'Prof. Richard Feynman')
>>> aluno = Aluno(12345, 'Poor Student', 20, physics)
>>> physics.procurar_por_alunos(aluno)
>>> physics.alunos
[<__main__.Aluno object at 0x7f3c0f609e80>]
```